# Is it possible to prove that $(x+1)\cdot\ln(x-1) > x\cdot\ln(x)$ for all integer values of $x>4$?

Tags: inequality, logarithms, exponentiation

Is it possible to prove that $(x+1)\cdot\ln(x-1) > x\cdot\ln(x)$ for all integer values of $x>4$?

It comes from a broader question about $(x-1)^{x+1} > x^x$ and the logarithm approach seems to be the most promising one.

Comment: It seems to be true only if $x> 4.141041525\ldots$.

Comment: Apologies, forgot to add the restriction

Comment: You like to prove that $\left( {1 - \frac{1}{n}} \right)^n  > \frac{1}{{n - 1}}$ for $n=5,6,7,\ldots$. Note that $\left( {1 - \frac{1}{n}} \right)^n$ is an increasing sequence.

Comment: Hint: restate it as $f(x+1)>f(x):=\frac{x}{\ln(x-1)}$.

Comment: It is enough to show that the function $f(x)=\frac{\log(x)}{x+1}$ has a local maximum at $x=\frac 1{W\left(1/\mathrm e\right)}\approx 3.59112\ldots$, where $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function, and $f$ is decreasing on $\left(\frac 1{W\left(1/\mathrm e\right)},\infty\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(x+1)\cdot\ln(x-1) - x\cdot\ln(x)=:y$$

$$y' = \frac{x+1}{x-1} + \ln(x-1) - 1 - \ln(x)\\
y'=\frac{2}{x-1}+\ln\frac{(x-1)}{x}\\
y'>0\ \text{when,}\ x\ge5\\
\therefore y \text{ is increasing for}\ x \in[5,\infty) \cdots I$$

Now, $y_{x=5}=6\ln4-5\ln5=\ln(\frac{4096}{3125})\approx0.2719>0 \cdots II$

Hence, $y>0\ \forall x>4, x\in\mathbb Z\ [\text{from I and II}]$

$\therefore (x+1)\cdot\ln(x-1)>x\cdot\ln(x);\ \forall x>4, x\in\mathbb Z\ $